# Avoid repeated lines of code when enum case have the same associated values?

Tags: ios, swift, enums

I am writing a Router class to drive my API (CRUD)as prescribed in the Alamofire docs, and annoyingly enough, I end up repeating the same lines of code over and over. Here is part of the enum:

```
enum Router: URLRequestConvertible {
  static let baseURLString = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx"

  case ReadFeed([String: AnyObject])
  case CreateUser([String: AnyObject])
  case LogIn([String:AnyObject])
  case CreatePost([String:AnyObject])
  case ReadUser(id: String, parameters: [String:AnyObject])
  case ListUsers([String:AnyObject])
  case UpdateUser([String: AnyObject])
  case DestroyUser(String)
  case ReadImage(String)
  case Subscribe(String, to: String)

  var method: Alamofire.Method {
    switch self {
    case .CreateUser, .CreatePost:
      return .POST
    case .ReadUser, .ListUsers, .ReadImage, .ReadFeed, .SearchUser:
      return .GET
    case .UpdateUser:
      return .PUT
    case .DestroyUser:
      return .DELETE
    case .LogIn:
      return .POST
    }
  }

  var path: String {
    switch self {
    case .ReadFeed:
      return "/feed"
    case .CreateUser:
      return "/users"
    case .CreateColumn:
      return "/columns"
    case .UploadImage:
      return  "/profilepictures"
    case .ListUsers:
      return "/users"
    case .ReadUser(let id, _):
      return "/users/\(id)"
    case .CreatePost:
      return "/posts"
    case .LogIn:
      return "/users/login"
    case .ReadImage(let ownerID):
      return "/image/\(ownerID)"
    case .Subscribe(let user, _):
      return "/users/\(user)"
    case .UpdateUser(let username, _):
      return "/users/\(username)"
    case .DestroyUser(let username):
      return "/users/\(username)"
    }
  }

  // MARK: URLRequestConvertible

  var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    switch self {
    case .CreateUser(let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .CreatePost(let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .UploadImage( _, let image, let parameters):
      mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
       return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .UpdateUser(_, let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .ListUsers(let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .ReadFeed(let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .ReadUser(_, let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .LogIn(let parameters):
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    case .Subscribe(_, let newSubscription):
      let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = ["subscriptions": ["$push": newSubscription]]
      return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
    default:
      return mutableURLRequest
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, the formula

```
case .XXX(let parameters):
  return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
```

is repeated times and times over. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: why not put all those in one case with comma seperation ?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that in all cases you have `parameters`, so maybe it should not be associated with each case. A struct similar to this may be useful:

```
struct RouterInfo {
    let type: Router
    let parameters: [String:AnyObject]
}
```

And then only some cases in the enum `Router` could have some associated values that are specific to those cases.

Then, your `var URLRequest` should probably be part of the struct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do something like this

```
 switch self {
case .CreateUser(let parameters), .CreatePost(let parameters):
  return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
case .UploadImage( _, let image, let parameters):
  mutableURLRequest.HTTPBody = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 1)
   return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
case .UpdateUser(_, let parameters), .ListUsers(let parameters), .ReadFeed(let parameters), .ReadUser(_, let parameters), case .LogIn(let parameters):
  return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.URL.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
case .Subscribe(_, let newSubscription):
  let parameters: [String:AnyObject] = ["subscriptions": ["$push": newSubscription]]
  return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
default:
  return mutableURLRequest
}
```

In this way you will have minimal repetition.

Answer (score 0):

you can define more variable named 'parameters' which is a type of [String: AnyObject]? and return those parameter for each cases.

Note that the .get service require nil for parameters and if .post service has no parameter, return [:] (empty dictionary)

```
var parameters: [String: AnyObject]? {
    switch self {
    case .login(let username, let password):
        return [
            "username": username,
            "password": password
        ]
    case .getUserInfo(let userID):
        return ["userID": userID]
    default: 
        return nil
    }
}
```

Then call this variable in mutableURLRequest

```
var URLRequest: NSMutableURLRequest {
    let URL = NSURL(string: Router.baseURLString)!
    let mutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: URL.URLByAppendingPathComponent(path))
    mutableURLRequest.HTTPMethod = method.rawValue

    // Get your parameters via calling the variable
    return Alamofire.ParameterEncoding.JSON.encode(mutableURLRequest, parameters: parameters).0
}
```